# Series connection of capacitors

Tags: capacitor, series

I have some questions for the series connection of capacitors. It would be great if someone could help me get these.

What will happen for the below cases when you have 2 capacitors in series and 2 supplies connected to the extreme ends-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faoNRp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. When the supply V1 is a fixed voltage V1 and supply V2 is a fixed voltage V2. What will be the charge and the intermediate node voltage Vb?
2. When the supply V1 is ramping from 0 to a voltage Vs and supply V2 is a fixed voltage Vs. What will be the charge and the intermediate node voltage Vb here?
3. For case 2, When there is some initial charge on any capacitor , say C1 has Q_ini charge, how will the individual charge and intermediate voltage Vb get affected?

Comment: Make your life easier and replace the supplies with a single one supplying the sum of the two (or a difference considering the polarity). The reference can be added/subtracted later if you are really interested in the *potential* values of Va/b/c w.r.t. to your marked ground.

Comment: Series capacitors calculate like parallel resistances...

Comment: 1) Vb will be undefined, it can be anything initially.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The 2 supplies need to be separate. The case 2 is more of an actual use case.

Comment: @Neil_UK Yes can be anything initially. But once i am applying the voltages (say for the ramping case) the charge has to change for the caps right?

Comment: Yes, the change in charge is defined by the capacitor values and the change in Va and Vc, much the same way as when you're doing integration, you ought to consider the constant of integration, which only gets defined by the initial conditions.

Comment: @Neil_UK yes Q=CV equation. 
I have tried simulating these cases, and below are my observations -
(1) Vb is some random value. No charging happens as i believe the supplies are fixed voltages. No delta V
(2) Vb is defined only by the changing supply, irrespective of V2 (which can be same as V1 or any value ). Here then is Q2 (across C2, C2*(Vb- Vc)) correct?  
(3) Here again Vb is defined only by the changing supply, irrespective of V2 (which can be same as V1 or any value ).
this is what is a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

This C divider ratio will have an intermediate V depending on the ratio of C1/(C1+C2) across C2 of the difference V.

So the smallest C value has the highest V and then leakage R ratio’s will affect the steady state V after some time constant T=(Rp1+Rp2)*C1//C2 to 64% Delta V @ 1T

This “Capacitive Transformer” method is a common method for sampling a single phase HVAC , not shown here, to a safe LV for sensing using Vb with V2 =0V or grounded.

e.g. a bushing 100 pF 100kV cap (arc protected) integrated in porcelain, to a 10uF cap to get 1V ,  used by ABB.

Can you think of any practical use for this in a switching S&H  circuit? For DC and small signals? Can you imagine any effects in switching cascaded FET’s at high speed with a large Ciss load from a smaller Coss driver with higher RdsOn?